# Error "object required" in VBA , referred to duplicate questions

Tags: vba, object, required

My purpose is to split a task into constituent tasks and find the most important one.The macro is written in "May" sheet of workallotment.xlsm and the tasks are in tasks.xlsx

For example:

```
                                   Constituents  Constituents  Important Imp
Praveen T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6     T1+T2+T3 =T5  T3+T5+T6 =T9     T1      T6
         4  3   1   2   8   9               
Karthik P1  P2  P3  P4          " among T1,T2,T3- T1 takes more time".its imp       
         6  3   2   2                       
Walter  c1  c2  c3  c4                      
        1   2   3   4                       
Arvind  g1  g2  g3                          
         2  1   3                           
Sreelatha   h1  h2  h3                          
            2   1   1
```

Code:

```
Sub workallotment()
    Dim workallotmentWB, tasksWB As Workbook
    Dim waSheet As Worksheet
    Dim str(9) As String
    Dim splitArray() As String, S(10) As String
    Dim col_new As Integer

    Dim wa_nameRng As Range

    Dim r As Integer, max As Integer, imps As String
    Dim wa_nameRow, wa_firstRow, wa_lastRow As Integer  'work allotment rows
    Dim t_firstRow, t_lastrow As Integer                'task rows

    Dim curTaskCol As Integer   'current task column
    Dim wa_tmpcol As Integer    'work allotment, temp column


        Set workallotmentWB = ThisWorkbook
        Set tasksWB = Workbooks.Open("E:/tasks.xlsx")

        'notes on data structure:
        '- tasks workbook:
            'first name starts in A1 of "Sheet1"
        '- workallotment workbook:
            'first name starts in A2 of Sheet named "workallotment"
            'tasks are to be written starting in B2
            'in Row 1 are headers (number of days)

        t_firstRow = 1
        wa_firstRow = 2
        wa_nameRow = 0

        Set waSheet = workallotmentWB.Worksheets("May")             ' in this file - workallotment.xlsm

        With tasksWB.Worksheets("May")                              ' in tasks.xlsx which is attached

            'finding the last rows
            t_lastrow = .Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).row + 1
            wa_lastRow = waSheet.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).row

            'goes through all the names in tasks_Sheet1
            For r = t_firstRow To t_lastrow Step 2


                Set wa_nameRng = waSheet.Range("A:A").find(.Range("A" & r).Value, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

                If Not wa_nameRng Is Nothing Then

                    wa_nameRow = wa_nameRng.row

                    curTaskCol = 2
                    wa_tmpcol = 2

                    Do While Not IsEmpty(.Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value)

                        For C = 1 To .Cells(r + 1, curTaskCol).Value
                            waSheet.Cells(wa_nameRow, wa_tmpcol).Value = .Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value
                            wa_tmpcol = wa_tmpcol + 1
                        Next C

                        curTaskCol = curTaskCol + 1

                    Loop

                End If

            Next r

        End With

        MsgBox ("done")



    For r = t_firstRow To t_lastrow Step 2                ' loop to find importance

    col = 2                                               'setting to initial col
    curTaskCol = 17    ' position input - constituent jobs at 17th col in tasks.xls

    Do While Not IsEmpty(tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value)

     str(curTaskCol - 16) = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol).Value
            ' reading input to first array of string element

    substr = Left(str(curTaskCol - 16), Application.WorksheetFunction.find("=", str(curTaskCol - 16)) - 1)         ' if T1+T2=T3 it'll look before "=" symbol
    MsgBox (substr)
    splitArray() = Split(substr, "+")  ' if T1+T2 it will be split as T1 & T2


    For i = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray)

        S(i + 1) = splitArray(i)          ' assigning split elements to string array

        Next i
    For i = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray)
        col_new = 2                   ' checking from 2nd column


        Do While Not IsEmpty(tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new).Value)
         If (S(i + 1) = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new).Value) Then                 'initialising max and imps
          imps = S(i + 1)       ' most important job

          max = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r + 1, col_new).Value

        End If                       ' maximum time taken for task
        col_new = col_new + 1
        Loop

        For j = LBound(splitArray) To UBound(splitArray)

          col_new = findcol(S(j + 1), r, tasksWB)


          If (max < tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r + 1, col_new).Value) Then
          max = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r + 1, col_new).Value
          imps = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new).Value

        End If
        Next j

        Next i
    tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, curTaskCol + 6).Value = imps
                                ' assign most IMPORTANT task on 6th column from current column
    curTaskCol = curTaskCol + 1               ' RUNTIME ERROR 1004

     Loop


     Next r


End Sub

Public Function findcol(S As String, row As Integer, theWB As Workbook) As Integer
    Dim col As Integer, addr As Integer
    col = 2                  ' checking from column 2
    'Set tasksWB = Workbooks.Open("E:/tasks.xlsx")


    Do While Not IsEmpty(theWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(row, col).Value)

         If (StrComp(Trim(S), Trim(theWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(row, col).Value)) = 0) Then
           addr = col                         ' if task string is found in column
        End If
        col = col + 1                            ' return column found
        Loop
        findcol = addr
End Function
```

Comment: Where is you error? Plz be specific

Comment: Error in the function call line : "col_new = findcol(S(j + 1), r)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Krishnan,

In your main proc `workallotment` you declare the variable `tasksWB`.

In your method 'findcol' you then reference `tasksWB`. It looks like you've pulled this code out of the main proc. The tasksWB only has scope within `workallot` and so you need to give `findcol` this object so it will have it within it's scope as well.

I would recommend that you pass the tasksWB into the method, as a third parameter.

Your method would then look as follows.

Edit for your comment of why findcol doesn't return. The `Exit Function` will ensure that the method is exited immediately after setting the return value. Without this you would end up in the asking for the correct task name again.

```
Public Function findcol(S As String, row As Integer, theWB as Workbook) As Integer
    col = 2                  ' checking from column 2
    Do While Not IsEmpty(theWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(row, col).Value)
        If (S = theWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(row, col).Value) Then                   
           findcol = col                         ' if task string is found in column                      
           Exit Function
        End If
        'MsgBox ("Enter correct task names")  Not sure why this is here.
        col = col + 1                            ' return column found
    Loop
End Function
```

and you'd call it with

```
col_new = findcol(S(j + 1), r, tasksWB)    ' ERROR line function to find column of task string
```

This will ensure that you do not "leak" your variable definition into global scope, and that you also ensure that your method doesn't depend on external globals.

Edit 3:
Your findcol is still wrong.

```
Public Function findcol(S As String, row As Integer, theWB As Workbook) As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    '******* you don't need this because you can exit early
    'Dim addr As Integer
    col = 2                  ' checking from column 2

    '*****   THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE REMOVED because you are using theWB being passed in *****
    'Set tasksWB = Workbooks.Open("E:/tasks.xlsx")


    Do While Not IsEmpty(theWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(row, col).Value)

        '****** this line must use theWB
        'If (StrComp(Trim(S), Trim(tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(row, col).Value)) = 0) Then
        If (StrComp(Trim(S), Trim(theWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(row, col).Value)) = 0) Then

            '*************  you can exit early once you've found what you need.
            'addr = col                         ' if task string is found in column
            findcol = col
            exit function            
        End If
        col = col + 1                            ' return column found
    Loop
    ' You can exit early so don't need this.
    ' findcol = addr
End Function
```

You should probably do a check when you call the function that the value hasn't returned 0, eg

```
new_col = findcol( .... )
if new_col = 0 then
   msgbox "couldn't find the column with that str" & S(j + 1)
end if
```

Comment: Done!!!That error rectified long back .But still I m getting Runtime error-Automation error in line after the function call statement in sub workallotment() " If (max < tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r + 1, col_new).Value) Then max = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r + 1, col_new).Value imps = tasksWB.Worksheets("May").Cells(r, col_new).Value "

Comment: I found out what the error is...When the function opens Workbooks.Open("E:/tasks.xlsx"). It closes it when it comes back to sub workallotment().So it shows Runtime error because tasks.xlsx is not open.Can you help me fix this situation alone..please

Comment: Your code isn't closing the workbook. So it won't get closed just because it exists the method. You might want to re-paste your code above, to show what it now looks like. It's not clear from your various answers what you have done now. A Runtime error could be caused by the workbook not being in the place it says it is, or the worksheet name not being there.

Comment: I have edited the code and pasted it above after making changes

Comment: You're `findcol` is wrong. You are passing in the `theWB` in and then instantiating a new `tasksWB` by opening your testbook again. that will close the original file. only use `theWB` in your `findcol` method.

Comment: Thank you...I got the result correctly printed...But still I get a Runtime error message...after getting correct result ..Runtime error 1004 - Application defined or object defined error . I have re-pasted the code againa above after doing the changes you mentioned

Comment: Ive updated my answer with Edit 3. showing what the findcol should look like.

Answer (score 1):

`tasksWB` isn't recognized in the `findcol` function as it is declared as `Private` (=`Dim`) in the main process.

Declare it at the top of your module, and it'll work! ;)

Comment: Thanks!!!The old error has been rectified if I declare TasksWB in the function. But I m getting another error "Runtime - Automation error" and I m asked to "enter the task names correctly" but all strings are correct.But the "if" condition is not getting executed in the function if the string is found